# Spark UDF serialization failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, serialization, user-defined-functions

When registering and using a UDF in Spark with Scala
I got the following error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field.

**Background:**
In order to create a base class for UDF's
to create Accumulator and measure UDF run time

I created the following base class:

```scala
abstract class UDFWithAccumulator[T1, T2](withAccumulator: Boolean) extends Serializable {

    val accumulator: LongAccumulator = if (withAccumulator) SparkSession.getDefaultSession.get.sparkContext.longAccumulator(s"${getClass.getSimpleName}Acc") else null

    protected def getFunction(): T1 => T2

    private val fn: T1 => T2 = getFunction()

  def udf(): T1 => T2 = if (withAccumulator) fnWithAccumulator else fn
  private def fnWithAccumulator(input: T1): T2 = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val res: T2 = fn(input)
    accumulator.reset()
    accumulator.add(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
    res
  }

}
```

Then using it in the following way:

```scala
class CreateRulesDataUdf(withAccumulator: Boolean) extends UDFWithAccumulator[mutable.WrappedArray[Row], RulesData](withAccumulator) {
    val DEFAULT_RULES_ARR: Array[Rule] = Array()

    override protected def getFunction(): mutable.WrappedArray[Row] => RulesData = {}
```

Where RulesData definition is:

```scala
case class RulesData(rules: mutable.WrappedArray[Rule], botnet_id: String) extends Serializable
```

UDF registration is done in the following way:

```scala
session.udf.register(CREATE_RULES_DATA_UDF, new CreateRulesDataUdf(withAccumulator).udf())
```

When calling the UDF I got the following error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field.

I was able to work around the issue when changing the base class implementation to the following code(the only change is that I'm not using a field to store the functionRef):

```scala
abstract class UDFWithAccumulator[T1, T2](withAccumulator: Boolean) extends Serializable {

  val accumulator: LongAccumulator = if (withAccumulator) SparkSession.getDefaultSession.get.sparkContext.longAccumulator(s"${getClass.getSimpleName}Acc") else null

  protected def getFunction(): T1 => T2
  def udf(): T1 => T2 = if (withAccumulator) fnWithAccumulator else getFunction()
  private def fnWithAccumulator(input: T1): T2 = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val res: T2 = fn(input)
    accumulator.reset()
    accumulator.add(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
    res
  }

}
```

**Question**
I'm trying to understand why this workaround solves the issue and why spark failed to serialize/Deserialize the function?